# What is the way to set up an authentication mechanism using keycloak initial access token?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, architecture, keycloak

I want to develop an authentication mechanism for 3rd party applications using keycloak initial access tokens. But I want to do this **only by using the access tokens** that I have generated in the keycloak. For example, I will give a generated token to the user and allow him to log into the application. Is this possible? How can i do that?
[Initial Access Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvSX8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm not sure it is a good idea to use "initial access token" for authorizing requests to your own resources. It might even not be allowed. As per [the doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_initial_access_token):

> An initial access token can only be used to create clients

Second, don't use keycloak libs for Spring as suggested in other answer. It is [very deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

Last, a REST API secured with Oauth2 is a **resource-server** (and not a client). As so, the dependency should be `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. Spring doc is pretty extensive on the subject. You can also have a look at [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for resource-server configuration (and OAuth2 definitions).

Once the resource-server (Spring REST API) is configured, clients will have to authorize their requests as normal for OAuth2: provide with an `Authorization` header containing a `Bearer` access-token (a JWT issued by Keycloak to the client with one of standard flows: client-credentials or authorization-code depending you need to authorize the client itself or a user behind it).

#### Edit

I might have misunderstood your need. If what you want is having new clients register themself programmatically on your Keycloak instance, then those clients will just issue a REST request to **Keycloak server** API with the "initial access token" in Authorization header as normal.

Once registered, those clients will be able to call you resource-servers as described in my initial answer.